# BigQuery table labels disappear after updating data

Tags: google-bigquery

I have set labels for BigQuery tables using the web user interface. However when I append new data to the table using either the the Python or Nodejs client library (see below for code examples), the label disappears. Is this expected behaviour? And if so is there any way to update table data without loosing it's labels?
Nodejs:

```js
const metadata = {
      sourceFormat: "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
      autodetect: true,
      writeDisposition: "WRITE_APPEND",
};
const [job] = await bigquery
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId)
      .load(filename, metadata);
```

Python:

```py
data.to_gbq(
            'datasetname.tablename', 
            project_id='projectid', 
            if_exists='replace'
        )
```

Comment: Can you share the Python code you tried or a bigger snippet of your code?

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem using Python but it worked correctly for me

Comment: hhmmm well that is the behaviour I was hoping for, which is good news, thanks! I've added the Python code that is being used. I am guessing if_exists='replace' actually destroys the table rather than just replace the data. My Nodejs example is specifically appending the data though so I am sure this behaviour is wrong. I've filled an issue for the Nodejs client.

Comment: also realised part of the nodejs example was missing, whoops. added now.

Comment: Yes, this replace attribute is something like "delete the table and create another one". Now it makes sense.  About the Node code, it should be working

Comment: Did it answer your question? If yes, consider accepting :)

Comment: I am waiting to get a response for the issue I raised in the nodejs lib. I think the accepted answer should specify whether it is possible to preserve labels with the nodejs library, or whether it is similar a bug. Your answer was very helpful though, I gave you the upvote.

Comment: @rmesteves I see in comments that you were successful in adding labels to bigquery tables. I wanted to do the same but programatically. I use Airflow BigqueryOperator for creation of queries and dumping the data to destination table. I am not able to add labels during the creation of table using BigqueryOperator . If you know could you help on that? [This is the link to the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992114/add-labels-to-bigquery-tables-using-airflow-bigqueryoperator) and things i have tried

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing your problem with the code below and as you can see in the images the labels were not affected.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client("my-project-id")

filename = "/path/to/file"
dataset_ref = client.dataset("dataset_id")
table_ref = dataset_ref.table("table_id")

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON

with open(filename, "rb") as source_file:
     job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
```

1. Table with Labels created through interface
   [image]
2. Running the code
   [image]
3. Labels were not modified
   [image]

**EDIT**:

When using Pandas to write to BigQuery, if you set the attribute "if_exists" as "replace", the table will be drop and another table will be created as can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html).

[image]